# Need API to programmatically make website available on specific domain/subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, deployment, website, wildcard

I have a platform/program running on SERVER_1 with registered domain e.g. example.com. Registered user can add some data and program will generate HTML pages (static website) according to that data. A user also defines the **NAME** of the website.

GOAL is to upload these generated static websites on SERVER_2, so they have subdomain [**NAME**].example.com. So, every new website should have its one subdomain.

Where I am now:

I have the idea to set wildcard subdomain *.example.com pointing to SERVER_2, and then, on SERVER_2 to have virtual hosts which will examine which website to show according to a subdomain.

Problem is that I need to programmatically do everything of this (generate the site, upload to SERVER_2, setup subdomain ...) and I need a practical way to do this using an API or do it using SSH, but I'm failing to find a solution that will fit my needs 100%.

I have done research on:

Firebase google - good API and docs but I haven't seen virtual hosts, also they have limits on number of projects per account

Plesk - old XML API, virtual hosts

S3 - easy website deploy but does not fit subdomain mapping needs

Does somebody know what is the best and most practical way to do all of this fully automatically (back-end Spring-boot java)? Thank You!

Comment: You can create template text files and fill in variable values, right? Do the same thing with a web server configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Use nginx.
Upload html files either via scp or sftp protocols. Amend that upload with a config file for nginx (separate file per each domain is standard for nginx). Then ssh to server and issue `sudo systemctl reload nginx`